# Django: How can i get the url of a template by giving the namespace?

Tags: django, django-templates, render, reverse, django-context

While i'm rendering a template i would like to retrieve the url of the template by giving the namespace value and not the path. For example instead of this:

```
return render(request, 'base/index.html', {'user':name})
```

i would like to be able to do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

return render(request, reverse('base:index'), {'user':name})
```

but the above produces an error. How can i do it? Is there any way to give the namespace to a function and get the actual path?

Extended example:

### - urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('base.urls', namespace='base')),
)
```

### - app base: urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('base.views',
   url(r'^/?$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

### - app base: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def homepage(request):
   '''
   Here instead of 'base_templates/index.html' i would like to pass
   something that can give me the same path but by giving the namespace
   '''
   return render(request, 'base_templates/index.html', {'username':'a_name'})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `base/index.html` is the template name. `reverse` is used for reverse resolution of url names. Your logic is wrong. You cannot user `reverse` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template names are hard coded within the view. What you can also do is that you can pass the template name from the url pattern, for more details see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

    urlpatterns = patterns('base.views',
       url(r'^/?$', 'index',
          {'template_name': 'base_templates/index.html'},
          name='index'),
       )
```

Then in view get the template name:

```
def index(request, **kwargs):
    template_name = kwargs['template_name']
```